# Javascript dependently sort table columns

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Lets say I have the following dataset

```
Company    S1   S2   S3
Apple.com  0.40 0.28 1.00
Google.com 0.30 0.58 0.99
```

Lets say the above is in an HTML table.

I have managed to figure out how to sort S1, S2 and S3 individually. However, Im intrested to know how I can sort them in groups.

- If I'm sorting highest to lowest for S1. Apple should be on top
- If im sorting S2 from highest to lowest. Google Should be on top.
- If I'mm sorting based on S1 and S2, Google should be on top because
  their average is higher.
- Lastly, if I sort based on S1 and S3, Apple should be higher.... The
  raw data is being pulled from a database and populated using PHP. I
  understand that I can do this logic in PHP, however, I want the user
  to have the ability to reorder the list on the fly*.

Any jQuery/Javascript way of doing this?
**EDIT:**

Note [this](http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/).

The author sorts each column when pressed. However, I want the ability to "check" two columns and have it sort by their average.

**EDIT2:**

I want to select n number of columns to average. where n is an element of [1..infinity].

Only want high on top. That is, no need for revers sorting.

Comment: Can you please more clearly describe the criteria by which you want to sort the array?  It seems like you're talking about sorting based on the outcome of a function of multiple column values.

Comment: So What do you want if you know how to sort? in Your case you have to calculat  total  of the columns and then sort.

Comment: heres a plugin that has the features you want: http://jqgrid.com/jqgrid/demos/jqgrid-standalone/preserve-selection-horizontal-scroll-on-sort... (This may be overkill)

Comment: I have updated my question with an example that sort of works.

Comment: You want the ability to check two columns:  **Just** two?  Or any number?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Any number of columns. But a linear approach could work. I think at worst I will have 15. Not sure at this point.

Comment: You would have to check if the column values are all numeric values at first. This is quite feasible with an array containing each row and their columns values.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would do it, based on sorting plain objects, if you can then turn this back into your tables:

```
var sortCompanies = function(cols, companies) {
    if (!cols || !cols.length) {
        companies.sort(function(a, b) {return a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0});
        return companies;
    }
    companies.forEach(function(company) {
        company.sortKey = 0;
        cols.forEach(function(col) {
            company.sortKey += (company[col] || 0);
        });
    });
    companies.sort(function(a, b) {return b.sortKey - a.sortKey;});
    return companies;
};

var companies = [
    {name: 'Apple.com', S1: 0.40, S2: 0.28, S3: 1.00},
    {name: 'Google.com', S1: 0.30, S2: 0.58, S3: 0.99}
];

sortCompanies(['S1'], companies);             //=> Apple, Google
sortCompanies(['S1', 'S2'], companies);       //=> Google, Apple
sortCompanies(['S3'], companies);             //=> Apple, Google
sortCompanies(['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], companies); //=> Google, Apple
```